# Postgres, checking if a set contains another set

Tags: postgresql, dataset, subquery

Is there a better way to perform the following query? I'm trying to see if a user has all of the products in a certain category

```
SELECT t1.id 
  FROM 
    (SELECT count(product_id) as count, product_id FROM categories group by product_id) t1 
  INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT count(product_id) as count, product_id FROM categories INNER JOIN user_products on user_products.product_id = categories.product_id where user_id=116 group by product_id) t2 
  ON t1.id=t2.id 
  WHERE t1.count = t2.count
```

Comment: A couple of questions: "In a certain category"? Looks like you are checking all categories? How does a column `product_id` end up in a table named `categories` and why is `user_products` linked to a table `categories`? Do you have a UNIQUE index or PK defined for (product_id, user_id) in table user_products? Is the mismatch id <-> product_id intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this should work, but is this better ? Not sure...

```
select 
c.product_id
from categories c
left join user_products up on up.product_id = c.product_id and up.user_id = 116
group by c.product_id
having  sum (case when up.product_id is null then 0 else 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: The first one works, but performs a little slower than the subquery, but the latter doesn't work. It retrieves every category with the product in it, I could've typed it wrong, I'll look some more.

Comment: @scottkf: The query in its current state actually checks that the user has **no** products from `categories` at all - which contradicts the question. It would have to be something like `HAVING  count(up.product_id IS NULL) = 0`. But this can still be simplified ...

Answer (score 1):

This returns `TRUE` if a user has **all** products in 'category' (or none exist to begin with).

```
SELECT count(*) = 0
FROM   categories c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   user_products u
   WHERE  u.product_id = c.product_id
   AND    u.user_id = 116
   )
```

Should be faster than either of the solutions presented so far. (Provided my interpretation of the contradictory question fits.)

Comment: The other answer (Raphael Althaus) had this. too, but he removed it when the OP complained that "it did not work". The question is vary vague and possibly incomplete. (I prefer the NOT EXISTS, too. obviously)

Comment: @wildplasser: Ah, I see, Raphaël had almost the same query, except for the `count(*) = 0` ...